# A switch in my bindView is not running the expected cases

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-sqlite, android-viewbinder

I am trying to populate a list list with an `ImageView`, and three TextViews from an SQLite database. The data in the `TextView`s is what i expect it to be, but the `ImageView` never changes.

The `ImageView` is supposed to swap between two icons depending on the value of the Cursor at x row in y column. The column is populated with an `Integer` of `1` or `0`. If column y @ row x is 1 the red image should populate the `ImageView`. If 0 then the green image should.

That never seems to happen. It is always the red image, and the logcat always says the the value of cursor is 1.

```
04-14 08:24:04.188: A/example.stackoverflow.MainActivity@1840e274(6510):
04-14 08:24:04.191: D/cursor@iconHolder(6510): 1
04-14 08:24:04.191: D/icon(6510): true 1
04-14 08:24:04.191: V/date(6510): 2015-04-14 becomes April, 14
04-14 08:24:04.192: A/example.stackoverflow.MainActivity@1840e274(6510):
04-14 08:24:04.193: D/cursor@iconHolder(6510): 1
04-14 08:24:04.194: D/icon(6510): true 1
```

Here is a snippet of the SQLite database.

```
_id, weight,            height,               body_mass_index,   icon, date

"1","45.359233334609435","1778.003556007112","14.348300215310468","0","2015-04-14"
"2","47.627195001339906","1778.003556007112","15.06571522607599","1","2015-04-14"
"3","45.359233334609435","1778.003556007112","14.348300215310468","0","2015-04-14"
```

As you can see the icon should have been green then red and then green, but it was just red all three times. I really would appreciate some help with figuring out why my code doesn't work. Here is my `bindView`.

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.richListIcon);
        TextView weightInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personal_item1);
        TextView bmiInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.personal_item2);
        TextView dateInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp_item);

        int indexWeight;
        int indexBmi;
        int indexDate;

        String weightHolder = null;
        String weightModified = null;
        String bmiHolder = null;
        String bmiModified = null;
        String dateHolder = null;
        String upDateHolder = null;
        int iconHolder = 3;
        int iconSet;



        if (cursor != null) {
            Log.wtf(String.valueOf(getActivity()), "not null");
            iconHolder = (cursor.getColumnIndex
                    (DatabaseAdapter.DataManager.publicIconSetter));
            Log.d("cursor@iconHolder", String.valueOf(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow
                    (DatabaseAdapter.DataManager.publicIconSetter)));
            weightHolder = (String.valueOf
                    (cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex
                            (DatabaseAdapter.DataManager.publicWeight))));
            bmiHolder = (String.valueOf
                    (cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex
                            (DatabaseAdapter.DataManager.publicBMI))));
            dateHolder = (String.valueOf
                    (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                            (DatabaseAdapter.DataManager.publicDate))));

        }

        switch (iconHolder){
            case 0:
                iconSet = R.mipmap.green_icon;
                Log.d("icon", "false " + iconHolder);
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.d("icon", "true " + iconHolder);
                iconSet = R.mipmap.red_icon;
                break;
            default: iconSet = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
                Log.wtf("IVF_IconSetter", "Error, value from table is " + iconHolder);
        }
        iconView.setImageResource(iconSet);

    ...

    }
```

And my Crusor

```
 public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase database = dataManager.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {DataManager.UID,
            DataManager.Icon_Gained_Weight,
            DataManager.Weight,
            DataManager.BMI,
            DataManager.Date
    };
    String orderBy = DataManager.UID + " DESC";

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = database.query(DataManager.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, orderBy);
        if(cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        }

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

This problem has been solved by Playmaker420. I'll write out the answer if Playmaker420 chooses not to do so.

Comment: can you move the switch case into the if block and try

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did what you asked, but the result was exactly the same.

Comment: Did you  move  iconView.setImageResource(iconSet); this as well? If not move that also.

Comment: Yes, I did move that as well.

Comment: System.out.println(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("icon")); Can you try this and check the log

Comment: hmm very interesting. I accidentally typed `System.out.println(cursor.getColumnIndex("icon"));` and it printed out `1`, but then I realized that I made a mistake and corrected it. when I did it printed out `0`.

Comment: If you want to write that up as an answer please do, and I'll accept. if not I'll write it up when I wake up. Thank you very much  playmaker420.

Comment: Added that comment as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.out.println(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("icon"));
```

This should print the value of the column "icon"

Answer (score 0):

The method [getColumnIndex()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)) returns the index/position of the column and not its value. In your case, the value returned is always "1" since it is the second column (as you can see in the *columns* array). You should use the [getInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getInt(int)) method:

```
iconHolder = (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(/** here goes the column name */)));
```